# How do I enable the TypeScript tab of a Visual Studio project that's a console or windows service that's self-hosting web-pages

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, owin, self-hosting

Using Visual Studio 2015 I created a console application to self-host Owin with embedded static files.   Since Visual Studio doesn't know it's a web-site project, it ignores TypeScript files.   When I go to the project properties, the TypeScript tab's typically there in web projects is missing.

How do I enabled the TypeScript tab so that I can configure TypeScript and use Visual Studio 2015's built-in capabilities to compile TypeScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the .csproj file in a text editor and add the following line

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

I added it after this command:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: thanks that you took the effort to come here to post this q/a - helped me tons