# How to compile typescript in Visual Studio 2015 in pre- .net core console application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, typescript, compilation, console

I know that there is an easy answer when you move to .net core / dnx, but I need an answer in pre .net core world.

I have a console application, which self-hosts owin web server.
I added typescript files to the project and syntax highlighting / intellisense are working out of the box.

However I cannot figure out how do I compile the .ts files into javascript that my self-hosted web server will subsequently serve.

On the type script file properties tab the Build Action is selected as "TypeScriptCompile" but it does not seem to affect anything.

I'm guessing that writing a special msbuild script can achieve this, but I'm interested to know if there are simpler solutions that might be built in to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374041/284111) add the following line to your project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />`
```

After this it should start working. For your .ts files you can make the generated .js, .js.map visible in visual studio by adding these lines to your project file for each .ts file you have there:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="file1.js">
    <DependentUpon>file1.ts</DependentUpon>
  </None>
  <None Include="file1.js.map">
    <DependentUpon>file1.ts</DependentUpon>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This assumes that your .ts file (that is already in the project) is called file1.ts.

This will look similar to the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In properties, set the Custom Tool to `MSBuild:CompileTypeScript`. When you build it will generate the .js files if the .ts has been modified.

Comment: No dice - no error, but js file is not produced either.

Comment: Did you set the option to view all files? It doesn't add the files to the project when it generates them.

Comment: I know. Did not set the option, but watching the project folder where they are supposed to appear.